# Cell theory - What is it? - Reference request

Tags: reference-request, terminology

A user with $>10,000$ posts on sci.math called 'plutonium.archimedes' or 'AP' is constantly ranting about some [theory he deems superior to calculus](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=2679430&messageID=9711059#9711059)(a.k.a 'old math' I believe).

I can't find any reference to it anywhere or any description of what he is talking about, my first thought is that he is actually trolling, but to go on about it so constantly for years seems unlikely to be a troll.

> Is there any reference or texts I can read on cell-theory?

Comment: The correct terminology for this person is "crank" (I have not read about cell theory, but even if it is correct, that it can be simpler, more elegant and/or more powerful than calculus seems unlikely.)

Comment: AP is one of the most longevous and notorious loons on the internet.

Comment: I guess that vividly proves that $\mathrm{posts} \neq \mathrm{points}$ in any sensible forum. He is even mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet_celebrity

Comment: Those interested in reading AP's material, especially the older stuff, will find enough in this [18 January 2002 internet archive capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20020118042851/http://www.archimedesplutonium.com/) to keep busy for several months of reading.